# RESTKit object BOOL property to true/false JSON

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit

I have some objects which I'm sending to a server as JSON, in the request body, for a POST request. My question relates to boolean properties.

Say I have this property in an object I'm sending as JSON:

`@property (nonatomic) BOOL exported;`

By default, RestKit sends the boolean as either `1` or `0` in JSON. How can I setup RestKit so that all BOOLs are sent as `true` or `false` (which is the JSON boolean type).

Funnily enough, when going the other way, from JSON `true` or `false` to the BOOL property, RestKit reads the JSON `true/false` just fine, appropriately setting the property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem stems from the fact that SQLite does not have a boolean data type. So if I have a Boolean in my Core Data schema, it still ends up being stored as an integer in SQLite (with an int value of 1 or 0). So that's why I am seeing either `1` or `0` when outputting JSON via RestKit.

To correct this, I changed my property from my original question from `BOOL` to `NSNumber`:

`@property (nonatomic) NSNumber *exported;`

Whenever I assign to this property I need to set it with an `NSNumber` boolean value.

```c
   target.exported = [NSNumber numberWithBool:[self.exported boolValue]];
```

The JSON generated is now correct, because I am setting the NSNumber with `boolValue`:

```json
"exported" : true
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively; you could make it a bool instead of a BOOL and restkit will parse it properly.

`@property (nonatomic) bool exported;`

The reason it handles it properly in a read is that bool's are inherently just 1 or 0... so Restkit is smart enough to convert it to a BOOL.

Comment: Worth mentioning that this seems to no longer be an issue with 64-bit builds.

Answer (score 1):

```
Source type :NSCFBoolean 
Destination type : NSString
Discussion: Boolean literals true and false parsed from JSON are mapped to NSString properties as @"true" and @"false"
```

Source :[See This table](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-mapping#type-transformation)

Comment: That's fine, but I would like to map from the NSObject BOOL property to JSON boolean format, which is just `true` or `false` -- since JSON has a boolean type.

Answer (score 0):

If anybody uses RestKit with Swift, and has some trouble with it as I did, do not forget to add `dynamic` modifier to the property, and the `Bool` variable cannot be optional. Therefore use following:

```
dynamic var exported: Bool = false
```

Check question: [Bool Property Cannot be marked dynamic in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31131149/bool-property-cannot-be-marked-dynamic-in-swift)