# Bool Property Cannot be marked dynamic in swift

Tags: swift, key-value-observing

I'm trying to observe `Bool` value in swift using KVO and add `dynamic` modifier like this :

```
dynamic var isRestricted:Bool?
```

and the compiler say

> Property cannot be marked dynamic because its type canot be
>   represented in Objective-C

then what should I do? should I change to NSNumber for this? and What is the best practice for observing value then?

im using xcode 7 beta 2

Comment: did you try : `dynamic var isRestricted = Bool()`

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The actual problem is that *optional* booleans cannot be represented
in Objective-C (and therefore not marked dynamic). Using a non-optional

```
dynamic var isRestricted : Bool = false
```

should solve the problem.

Generally, the concept of "optionals" does not exist in `Objective-C`,
but optional references to instances of `NSObject` subclasses are 
bridged to nullable object pointers in Objective-C, so

```
dynamic var foo: Foo?
```

is allowed if (and only) if `Foo` is a subclass of `NSObject`.

Comment: It is partially correct. You **can** have optional properties marked as dynamic, but not booleans nor integers. For example you could have ``dynamic var myObject : MyClass?``

Comment: @vomi: You are completely right, thanks for the feedback. I hope that it is correct now.